# All heatmap colorbars displaying on last figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I've encountered a problem when plotting multiple heatmaps in Matplotlib (Python 3.6.0 in case it matters).

I have a function which plots a heatmap of some data, each heatmap in a separate figure. When I run this function for different arrays of data, the heatmaps all plot just fine in their respective figures, but for some reason, all of their colorbars display on the most recently plotted heatmap's figure, as shown in the image linked below.

Heatmap Bug

[image]

Note, this behavior persists when I attempt to plot the heatmaps manually without the function. Also note that the colorbars do not simply display on the most recently plotted figure, but only on the most recently plotted figure **containing a heatmap**. If I later plot a line plot for example, the colorbars do not display on this line plot but only on the last heatmap.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

# Function
f1 = lambda X, Y: X*X + Y*Y
f2 = lambda X, Y: X*X - Y*Y
f3 = lambda X, Y: X*Y - Y

# Grid on which function is to be evaluated
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
Xaxis = x[:, None]
Yaxis = y[None, :]

# Evaluate functions and create labels for plotting
Z1 = f1(Xaxis, Yaxis)
l1 = ['F1', '1']
Z2 = f2(Xaxis, Yaxis)
l2 = ['F2', '2']
Z3 = f3(Xaxis, Yaxis)
l3 = ['F3', '3']


# Function to plot heatmaps
def DoPlot(fig, fun, label):
    title = label[0]
    subscript = label[1]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    im = ax.imshow(fun, cmap=cm.viridis, interpolation='nearest', 
                   aspect='auto')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    cbar = colorbar(im)
    cbar.set_label(r'$Z_{{}}$'.format(subscript))
    fig.suptitle(title)
    fig.tight_layout()


# Plot the heatmaps

fig1 = figure()
fig2 = figure()
fig3 = figure()

DoPlot(fig1, Z1, l1)
DoPlot(fig2, Z2, l2)
DoPlot(fig3, Z3, l3)

show()
```

Comment: use `fig.colorbar(...)` (updating this code away from pylab would be trivial, btw)

Comment: @PaulH Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly. Could you make your comment an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to operate on the objects directly. So instead of `colorbar`, use `fig.colorbar`.

As you mention in your question `from pylab import *` is strongly discouraged. Upgrading your code to the object oriented interface is trivial:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

# Function
f1 = lambda X, Y: X*X + Y*Y
f2 = lambda X, Y: X*X - Y*Y
f3 = lambda X, Y: X*Y - Y

# Grid on which function is to be evaluated
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
Xaxis = x[:, None]
Yaxis = y[None, :]

# Evaluate functions and create labels for plotting
Z1 = f1(Xaxis, Yaxis)
l1 = ['F1', '1']
Z2 = f2(Xaxis, Yaxis)
l2 = ['F2', '2']
Z3 = f3(Xaxis, Yaxis)
l3 = ['F3', '3']


# Function to plot heatmaps
def DoPlot(fig, fun, label):
    title = label[0]
    subscript = label[1]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    im = ax.imshow(fun, cmap=pyplot.cm.viridis, interpolation='nearest', 
                   aspect='auto')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im)  # change: use fig.colorbar
    cbar.set_label(r'$Z_{{}}$'.format(subscript))
    fig.suptitle(title)
    fig.tight_layout()


# Plot the heatmaps
## change: use the pyplot function
fig1 = pyplot.figure()
fig2 = pyplot.figure()
fig3 = pyplot.figure()

DoPlot(fig1, Z1, l1)
DoPlot(fig2, Z2, l2)
DoPlot(fig3, Z3, l3)

pyplot.show()  ## change
```

You could also use a simple `for` loop to make the code less repetitive, but that's beyond the scope of this question.